# Recommended Formatting For PowerShell Arguments & Piping

Tags: powershell, parameters, formatting, arguments, structure

Take a command like this for example:

```
Get-AdUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} -Credential (Get-Credentials) -Server some.server.domain.com | Where-Object {DisplayName -like '*Reemer, Bob*'}
```

Of course it is gross, long and goes off the screen... what is the preferred way to split this up over multiple lines (to improve readability)?

Please give example that works in ISE, plain powershell interpreter and scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Of course it is gross and long...

It looks perfectly fine to me, but if you want shorter lines, I'd suggest [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1):

```
$ADUserParams = @{
  Filter = {Enabled -eq $true}
  Credential = (Get-Credential) 
  Server = 'some.server.domain.com'
}
Get-ADUser @ADUserParams | Where-Object {DisplayName -like '*Reemer, Bob*'}
```

You could also split the `Where-Object` filter scriptblock over multiple lines:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} -Credential (Get-Credentials) -Server some.server.domain.com | Where-Object {
  DisplayName -like '*Reemer, Bob*'
}
```

If you always reuse the same parameter value a lot, you can use [`$PSDefaultParameterValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values?view=powershell-5.1) as well:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*-AD*:Server'] = 'some.server.domain.com'
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} -Credential (Get-Credentials) | Where-Object {DisplayName -like '*Reemer, Bob*'}
```

And of course you can combine all of them:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*-AD*:Server'] = 'some.server.domain.com'
$ADUserParams = @{
  Filter = {Enabled -eq $true}
  Credential = (Get-Credential) 
}
Get-ADUser @ADUserParams | Where-Object {
  DisplayName -like '*Reemer, Bob*'
}
```

Comment: A hashtable, not an array

Comment: Hashtable, not an array.

Comment: Also I think instead of `@ADUserParams` you want `$AdUserParams`?

Comment: The @ is used for "splatting" making sure the right part of the hashtable goes into the right parameter.

Comment: @KolobCanyon No, the `@` in front of the variable name is how PowerShell knows that you're trying to use splatting and that the hashtable is not just a single argument. I've updated the answer with links to the documentation

Comment: @briantist aaaaand we're at it again :-D

Answer (score 5):

You can use the line continuation character, which is a backtick `` ` ``, as in [Bryce's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46938473/3905079).

But I don't like that at all. It's hard to see, makes editing a pain, and is overall ugly.

Instead, I recommend [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1).

This lets you define your parameters both dynamically, and with better formatting for the hashtable, making your function/cmdlet call nice and neat:

```
$myParams = @{
    Filter = { Enabled -eq $true }
    Credential = (Get-Credential)
    Server = 'some.server.domain.com'
}

Get-ADUser @myParams
```

Note that you can modify the hashtable as many times as you want before calling, and you can combine splatting with individual parameters.

```
$myParams = @{
    Filter = { Enabled -eq $true }
    Credential = (Get-Credential)
}

$myParams.Server = Get-MyCustomServer

Get-ADUser @myParams -Verbose
```

For the pipe, just use a newline directly after the `|` character. That part I like a lot and I use it all the time.

You can also use newlines inside a scriptblock, so you have great separation options there as well.

```
Get-ADUser @myParams -Verbose |
    Where-Object -FilterScript {
        $_.SomeProperty -eq $SomeValue
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a backtick to split a single line command to multiple lines.  Your command could end up looking like below:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} `
    -Credential (Get-Credential) `
    -Server some.server.domain.com | 
    Where-Object {DisplayName -like '*Reemer, Bob'}
```

Technically, the backtick is an escape character, and in this case we're escaping the carriage return.  The backtick can be used in other situations as well.

Comment: The backtick is not needed after a pipe (`|`).